# Bootstrap CSS for RadiobuttonList

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Radion button :

```
   <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Mode</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <asp:radiobuttonlist id="RadioButtonList1" cssclass="radio" autopostback="true" title="Please Select Mode of Payment"
          repeatdirection="Horizontal"
          onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:listitem>Cash</asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem>Cheque</asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem>Demand Draft</asp:listitem>
            <asp:listitem>Net Banking</asp:listitem>
        </asp:radiobuttonlist>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I have applied the Bootstrap css for:

- text box,
- dropdown list,
- textarea,
- buton, etc.

Everything looks fine, except for radiobutton list, which looks terrible:

[image]

How to solve this ?

Comment: did you assigned 100% for radiobuttonlist??

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai what do you mean?

Answer (score 16):

I could not use a `<label>` and `<input type="radio">`

So this is what I used:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="popiRadios" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem class="radio-inline" Value="1" Text="Cash" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem class="radio-inline" Value="0" Text="Cheque"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And it came out like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that even though Visual Studio's "intellisense" squirms at it, one can insert plain-old HTML attributes in <asp> objects, and they work.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of option you can choose, but i feel the best is in my experience is below.

1. First set style in the top of your form as shown below

   ```
   <style>
       .radiostyle {
         height: auto;
       }

       .radiostyle label {
           margin-left: 3px !important;
           margin-right: 10px !important;
       }
   </style>
   ```
2. Second you should apply the clss to the ASP.NET RadioButtonList control

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/GaDbZ/411/)

Add '`radio inline`' class to the '`label`'

html

```
<form>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="controls-row">
            <label class="control-label">Mode</label>
            <label class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" value="1" />First</label>
            <label class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" value="2" />Second</label>
            <label class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" value="1" />Third</label>
            <label class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" value="2" />Fourth</label>
            <label class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" value="1" />Fifth</label>
            <label class="radio inline">
                <input type="radio" value="2" />Sixth</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: but I don't have label control in my Radiobutton List

Comment: Sorry I said I don't have Label Property for my RadiobuttonList,I have only  <asp:listitem>Cash</asp:listitem>

Comment: This could help you http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/GaDbZ/412/, input elements are inline by default.

Comment: sorry I can't use Html Inputs in my Webforms becoz I have used master Page